# Loop starts again in C++

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int P[9],temp=0,g;    //temp for highest pancakes, g for person number
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
          cout<<"Enter the number of pancakes eaten by person "<<i+1<<" ";
          cin>>P[i];

          if(P[i]>temp)
          {
              temp=P[i];
              g=i+1;
          }
     }

    cout<<"Most pancakes were ate by person "<<g<<endl<<temp;
    return 0;

 }
```

The Problem is That the loop starts again if i enter a value less than 10 for the last person.
if i enter P[9]<10 the loops runs again. Like when i enter value 0 pancakes, It the next output line is- 
Enter the number of pancakes eaten by person 2

But if i enter a value greater than 10 then the loop seems to work alright. Whats the problem here?

Comment: when confused about loops, the first thing you should do is properly format and indent your code (especially the brackets)

Comment: when peer reviewed, I did that for you ;)

Comment: Hint: P[9] creates an array with 9 elements (ranging from 0 to 8). Your for loop runs from 0 to 9.

Comment: The code is very ugly! Things which must be better: Use exactly ONE constant to define the range of an array, controls the loop which runs over the array and protect any access of an array. Please also do not use two types of indexing if possible. i, i+1,g ... , please give variables names which makes the code readable. As you can see, one of the problems already brakes your code! And indentation and separation of code blocks is also important for readability! And as last: Please define each variable in a separate statement. Writing to cout should end with endl, because cout is buffered.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`); and address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`) if possible. **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) and `valgrind` if available.

Comment: `<conio.h>` is not a standard header. You should avoid it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - There is no need to avoid non-standard headers. You will always need non-standard headers for accessing OS specific functionality. You cannot write real world programs without OS specific functionality.

Comment: I actually agree (and on Linux I am a big fan of `<sys/mman.h>` & `<dlfcn.h>`), but the OP don't need `<conio.h>` for his program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int P[9]
```

defines an array of size 9, the elements being P[0] to P[8]

Since your loop is coded as `i < 10`, the last element entered is into P[9] which isn't part of your array. This leads to undefined behavior, so anything might happen. In this case, it is most likely that the compiler put the variable `i` directly behind the array in memory, so you are writing the last input value to `i` instead of the array. This is not guaranteed to happen with every platform and compiler, but is a specific quirk of your choice of compiler and platform.

Either change your array definition to

```
int P[10]
```

to get a 10 element array

or change your loop condition to

```
i < 9;
```

to get a loop wich runs 9 times.

Comment: The funny thing is, when the 10th value is stored, it probably overrides the temp variable

Comment: Thanks so much. Loop kept on restarting in Codeblocks while on turbo c++ it still gave a wrong answer.